# Forced graph works with one set of data but not with similar set of other data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

Both data sets, data and data1, are structurally similar however I am getting `Error: missing: undefined` error when a test data is used.

The observablehq is pointing the issue at:

```
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
       .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
       .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
       .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

The complete runable code is at: https://beta.observablehq.com/d/cab995be5e806a80

`data = JSON.parse('{"nodes":[{"id":"K","group":1},{"id":"C","group":1},{"id":"J","group":1},{"id":"H","group":1},.....],"links":[{"source":"K","traget":"C","value":1},{"source":"J","traget":"H","value":1},{"source":"D","traget":"K","value":1},.....]}')`
**Above data set doesn't work**

`data1 = JSON.parse('{"nodes":[{"id":"Myriel","group":1},{"id":"Napoleon","group":1},{"id":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},...],"links":[{"source":"Napoleon","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Mlle.Baptistine","target":"Myriel","value":8},{"source":"Mme.Magloire","target":"Myriel","value":10},{"source":"Mme.Magloire","target":"Mlle.Baptistine","value":6},...]}')`
**This data set works**

I am clueless on debugging this as both data structure look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"source":"K","traget":"C","value":1}
```

Most likely, the issue is that `target` is misspelled as `traget` in one of the datasets.

Comment: I am embarrassed! Thanks @tmcw